# resizeTo() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Running Firefox 12.0.  I'm just starting to write a app that I want to run on localhost.  I want it to open it in a (600,400) window, but since I have Firefox set to open everything in tabs I thought I could bookmark it and right-click to open it in a new window.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.resizeTo(600,400);
});
```

Doesn't work.  Is what I am trying to do possible?

Thanks,  Jim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible, unless the window was opened through javascript using `window.open` and has only 1 tab in it.

> Since Firefox 7, it's no longer possible for a web site to change the default size of a window in a browser, according to the following rules:
>    - You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
>    - You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

[**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo)